# implementing short sounds in game with spritekit and swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I'm working on developing a game for iOS in `SpriteKit` framework and Swift code

I'm about to include sounds FX in the game, so in that way,  I need to use a lot of short sounds, playing some of them simultaneously, and synchronized with other sprite events. I don’t need precise control on volume, loops or stops. I am trying the following options with relative success:

- I tried to use `SKActions` to play sound files by means of `playSoundFileNamed`, preloading the variables: It´s really simple and fast , but it creates a continuous and growing memory allocation in OpenAl (XCode utils tracking) impossible to deallocate, making memory increasing up to app crash (around 100KB per sound)
- I tried to use `AudioToolbox` framework to play sound files by `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` but it has limitations to play several files at once
- I tried to use Audio player that uses `AVFoundation`. It doesn’t generate any memory leak but it makes my app delayed when I execute the action of playing sounds
- I tried  to use OpenAL but I cant find any helpful guide to implement easily  in the programming combo SpriteKit & Swift, only found in Objective-C

Which is the best approach to my goal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I preefer to play my sound using a nice library (a simple sharedInstance based on AVFoundation framework) called **SKTAudio** from [SKUtils](https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils/blob/master/SKTUtils/SKTAudio.swift):

```
func playSoundEffect(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
      print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
      return
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    do {
      soundEffectPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
      error = error1
      soundEffectPlayer = nil
    }
    if let player = soundEffectPlayer {
      player.numberOfLoops = 0
      player.prepareToPlay()
      player.play()
    } else {
      print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
    }
  }
}
```

---

It's very simple to use, you can declare it as a global var:

```
var audioManager : SKTAudio = SKTAudio.sharedInstance()
```

Then you can play an effect simple like this:

```
self.audioManager.playSoundEffect("menu-click.mp3")
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. SKTAudio  is what I use to play background music, but fails in performance when playing a lot of short sounds because it isn't fast enough for real time games. It makes delays and node count drops that gets the game lagging.

Answer (score 0):

First solution - use SKAudioNode. And if you are using SKS files you can place sound directly on the scene. Didn't have memory issues with that class. You have to check is scene's audioEngine is running before playing the sound - because for example you are transitioning to another scene.

Second -  you can try use ObjectAL (not OpenAL) http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/

Comment: thank you. SKAudioNode wouldn't fix my app since I am targeting for supporting iOS 7.1 and later, and SKAudioNode is available from iOS 9.0

Comment: I took a look at ObjectAL some time ago but I'm afraid it´s coded in Objetive-C and unfortunately I'm a beginner and don't know how to integrate the library in my swift code

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?